# Removing sensitive information from Sentry errors logs

Tags: sentry

I'm using Sentry to track all the errors on our production server, and I was wondering if it was possible to remove some sensitive data from the error logs :

For instance, I throw an error if a HTTP call to an API is failing. Sadly, I need to give the API access token as a query parameter of the request, and it is displayed in the error logs, in this format :

```
http

GET https://api.url?accessToken=abcdefg&otherparam=bar [400]

16:25:11
```

Can I hide or remove this accessToken ? It does not change between calls, so even setting it as an option somewhere so that it could be hidden from other people checking the Sentry logs would be alright.